# Mirroring while using Skeleton_tracker with Asus xtion Sensor

Tags: ros, xtion, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I'm using the Skeleton_tracker package @Chaos uploaded on Github, and it works pretty nice. However, I notice  when I load the depth image on Rviz, this image appears mirrored.

I have been reviewing the code, and I found this functions:

```
  depthStream_.setMirroringEnabled(true);

  vsColorStream_.setMirroringEnabled(true);
```

however, when I change this parameters the image works good but the tracking appears reflected. I set both parameters on true, in this way rgb image and tracking work good. Then I want to know if there is a way for getting all not reflected.
I thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221156/mirroring-while-using-skeleton_tracker-with-asus-xtion-sensor/) by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Fredylucas! Sorry for the late in my answer. I'm very busy lately...
I've notice the issue. As soon as I can, I will update the repository.
Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-12-17**:
Hi @Chaos, I'm using your package in a project, then, I want to ask you how must I cite it? I know this is no the way for asking it, but, I didn't found a mail or something like that for do it.

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-12-17**:
Hi @Fredylucas! My email address is in a comment in file skeleton_tracker/src/skeleton_tracker_node.cpp, line 37. There's also my full name.
Feel free to email me if you have issues with the package.